# where should I add external file to view in CI

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter

I'm trying to make view page in CodeIgniter,So I create it and in Controller it loads complete.
but when I add images and jQuery to it,they will not be loaded.
I made sub folder in view folder by name of **Files** and add to view for e.g like that

```
img src="Files/01.jpg"
```

but it will not be shown.
where should I place them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually make a folder called `files` in the main directory (where `system` and `application` reside), and then link to them using `base_url()`.

In your case, this would become

`<img src="<?= base_url(); ?>/files/01.jpg" />`

Hope that helps.

Comment: when I wanna use base_url() it will end program.in Controller it will show error that can't load page and in view it will not elements placed after base_url() function.

Comment: Load the URL helper to use base_url(): http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

When your view loads, the file paths will be relative to the directory the CodeIgniter index.php file is located in. If this is also the root directory of your site, you can refer to it in this way: `<img src="/Files/01.jpg" />`

Comment: Now I place 01.jpg in source folder where index.php application and system folder are there,and add <img src="01.jpg" /> to view page,but it does't show image.